# DigitalOcean App-platform: Host Dockerized Django app with Gunicorn on a non-root URL

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I recently deployed a dockerized Django app on DigitalOcean app platform alongside a react static site using the app spec file. Because of the static site, I opted to serve Django on a non-root URL (something like `https://example.com/api`) and serve the react app on the root URL (`https://example.com`).

If I visit the Django URL, Django comes up but throws a "path not found error". None of the routes on my Django app works. The solution doesn't seem to be on google either and I don't know why.

Here is what my app.yaml looks like:

```
name: test
region: nyc
services:
  - name: backend-api
    github:
      branch: deployment_app_platform
      repo: NdibeRaymond/test
      deploy_on_push: true

    http_port: 8000
    instance_count: 1
    instance_size_slug: basic-xxs
    source_dir: backend/
    dockerfile_path: backend/compose/django/Dockerfile
    routes:
      - path: /api

static_sites:
  - name: frontend
    environment_slug: node-js
    github:
      branch: deployment_app_platform
      repo: NdibeRaymond/test
      deploy_on_push: true

    source_dir: frontend/test/
    build_command: npm run build
    routes:
      - path: /
```

gunicorn configuration

```
exec /usr/local/bin/gunicorn test.wsgi --threads=3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --chdir /backend/test
```

root URL file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    path('', include('APIS.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I also tried

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    path('api/', include('APIS.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Can you spot what I'm missing?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of that Django "path not found" 404 error page you're getting? It should be instructive.